# Hash function the other way around

Tags: hash, algorithm

Is there anything that works like the opposite of a hash algorithm?

Today we know many hash algorithms, which take an input, perform some math on it, and output a value which is different than the input and can't be used to determine the input.

Is it possible to turn an input value into an output value, without being able to predict the output from the input, but having the output allows you to calculate the corresponding input?

As an example, I've read that a hashing algorithm is like turning a cow into ground beef. Obviously you can't turn ground beef back into a cow. What I'm looking for is like having a set of lego bricks. It's impossible to predict what someone will build out of them, but it's easy to determine what bricks they started with by looking at what they built.

Comment: That sounds like encryption... And this doesn't sound like a security question. You might want to look up "reversible hash", which is an oxymoron, but there have been lots of people wanting something like it.

Comment: It's also impossible for the output to be guaranteed smaller than input, due to the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).